# Jquery "insertbefore/insertafter" causes a blank page

Tags: jquery

i have a table like this

```
<body>
<div id="content">
<div>
<div style="float:left">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tbl" style="width:850px">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Select</th>
<th><span id="span_label">Label</span></th>
<th><span id="span_id">ID</span></th>
<th><span id="span_type">Type</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu0"><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value="07000000FCB74226"/></td>
<td id="sensor_pdu0" style="width:250px" >07000000FCB74226&nbsp;</td>
<td id="sensor_pdu0" style="width:250px" >SNSR: 1-1</td>
<td class="left" id="sensor_pdu0" style="width:250px" >zy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu1"><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value="380000000DDF3920"/></td>
<td id="sensor_pdu1" style="width:250px" >aaaaaaaaaa</td>
<td id="sensor_pdu1" style="width:250px" >SNSR: 1-2</td>
<td class="left" id="sensor_pdu1" style="width:250px" >be</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu2"><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value="E200000004D2CE42"/></td>
<td id="sensor_id" style="width:250px" >E200000004D2CE42&nbsp;</td>
<td id="sensor_pdu2" style="width:250px" >SNSR: 1-3</td>
<td class="left" id="sensor_pdu2" style="width:250px" >e</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu3"><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value="F900000003746C42"/></td>
<td id="sensor_id" style="width:250px" >F900000003746C42&nbsp;</td>
<td id="sensor_pdu3" style="width:250px" >SNSR: 1-4</td>
<td class="left" id="sensor_pdu3" style="width:250px" >c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu4"   style="width:250px" ><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value=""/></td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu5"   style="width:250px" ><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value=""/></td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu6"   style="width:250px" ><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value=""/></td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu7"   style="width:250px" ><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value=""/></td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu8"   style="width:250px" ><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value=""/></td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center" id="sensor_pdu9"   style="width:250px" ><input type="radio" name="sensorrd" value=""/></td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:250px" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="left:870px;padding-top:1px">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="btnbox" style="width:150px">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="center" valign="middle">
<br/>
<br/>
<button title="Up" onclick="moveupdown('up')"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>Move Selected Sensors</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<button title="Down" onclick="moveupdown('down')"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And there is two buttons name "UP" and "Down". 
When you select a radio box and click "UP"/"Down" button the selected row will be moved up/down.
The function of button like this

```
function moveupdown(arg){
var rd =  $('input:radio[name="sensorrd"]:checked');
var row = rd.parents("tr:first");
if (arg=="up") {
row.insertBefore(row.prev());
} else if (arg=="down") {
row.insertAfter(row.next());
}
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/27jcwps7/

The problem is that it often shows a blank page with radio box lable (such as :aaaaaa,bbbbbb or cccccc) on it.
Anybody can help me to solve this prob
[image]

Comment: Check out this fiddle, it works like a charm... http://jsfiddle.net/27jcwps7/ . Can you create a fiddle yourself demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Note: you realise you have 2 columns (first one only with a space) in your header, but only one in the rest of the table?

Comment: thank u for your reply. this is pesudo code. i will remove the first column.

Comment: have you checked your code in a browser other than IE?

Comment: yes. i tried it in chrome and firefox. both of them failed.  of course the real code is a little bit complex than pesudo code. it's very easy to see this case. i have no idea about this problem.

Comment: yeah but well, this works, I can't see any problems there. So it's either up to you to implement it correctly, or to create a fiddle which actually demonstrates the problem. As of now we can not even guess what the problem might be...